# How to use "MixItUp" plugin with Angular 4 App?

Tags: jquery, angular, web, plugins

I am trying to connect "MixItUp" plugin with Angular 4 app. But getting "$(...).mixitup is not a function" console error. can anybody help me out please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Console Error]

Comment: Please, don't post all of your code in images. That makes helping a real pain.

Comment: From next i will try to improve......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you load the `mixitup` from `node_modules` folder, so it will be probably this package, right?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mixitup

If so, that is not a jQuery plugin you are looking for. Its vanilla JS module. According to their github page, they dropped jquery as dependency in v3:

https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup/blob/v3/docs/mixitup-3-migration-guide.md

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is i had to use it via API method calling

EX: `const mixer = mixitup('#Container');`